ROS2 Humble C++: Calling a Service and waiting for a response within a ROS2 Callback
I'm working on a ROS2 Node that has a callback, that when it receives a new message should send a ROS2 Service call to a particular Server, and wait for a response before continuing. Furthermore, when it gets the response, depending on the response, I want it to handle things differently within the callback.
I've seen some examples:
https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/06f25e9c8801ea95a0c25260cb38f2f0c6af3ea0/demo_nodes_cpp/src/services/add_two_ints_client_async.cpp#L62-L73
But could never get it to work properly.
In an effort to keep things generic (without explicitly copying code), I've attempted the following approaches:
    void topic_callback(const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg) const
    {
        // Create service request
        auto request = std::make_shared<your_package::srv::YourService::Request>();
        // Populate request data here

        // Send service request
        auto future = client_->async_send_request(request);

        // Wait for response (you might want to do other things while waiting)
        if (rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(this->get_node_base_interface(), future) ==
            rclcpp::executor::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS)
        {
            auto response = future.get();
            // Process the service response here
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Service response: %s", response->value.c_str());
        } else {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Service call failed");
        }
    }

In this example, it works for the first call, but crashes when I attempt to basically states the node is added to the executor already, which makes sense, but what is the proper way to register it?
I did also try to use some form of Asynchronous service calls with something akin to:
    void topic_callback(const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg) const
    {
        auto request = std::make_shared<your_package::srv::YourService::Request>();
        // Populate request data

        auto future = client_->async_send_request(request,
            [this](std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<your_package::srv::YourService::Response>> future) {
                try {
                    auto response = future.get();
                    // Process the response
                } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Service call failed: %s", e.what());
                }
            });
    }

This issue fails, and I'm not sure if it has to deal with the way that async is implemented for ROS2 or perhaps my misunderstanding...
Lastly, I tried to get a future/promise approach to work:
        // Create a lambda to handle the service response
        future.then([promise = std::move(promise)](std::future<std::shared_ptr<your_package::srv::YourService::Response>> future) {
            try {
                auto response = future.get();
                // Process the response and set the promise value
                int result = process_response(response);
                promise.set_value(result);
            } catch (...) {
                // Handle exceptions
                promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
        });

With further issues.
I think I can do this with a mutex perhaps and a Multi-threaded executor in ROS2? I was unable to find a good example unfortunately.
Any help or full-end examples would be appreciated.
Thanks!

If you want to block in a callback (to wait for something), then you need to use a multithreaded executor and callback groups.
See this previous answer.

Can you try to add timeout value in your spin_until_future_complete()? Like this:
// Send the service request asynchronously
auto result = client_->async_send_request( request );

// Wait for the service response or timeout
if ( rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete( this->get_node_base_interface(), result, server_timeout ) ==
    rclcpp::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS)
{
    // Check if the response is valid
    if ( result.get()->is_valid ) {
        // SUCCESS: Process the valid response
        RCLCPP_INFO( this->get_logger(), "Service call succeeded." );
    } else {
        // FAILURE: Service call returned, but the response indicates failure
        RCLCPP_WARN( this->get_logger(), "Service call succeeded, but the response is invalid." );
    }
} else {
    // FAILURE: The service call failed to complete within the timeout
    RCLCPP_ERROR( this->get_logger(), "Service call failed to complete within the timeout." );
}

